# AXIS2 configuration for 1.5+ : No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found

Tags: java, apache-axis

When using AXIS 1.5+, we can see this warning while deploying web application :

> [WARN] No transportReceiver for
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance
>   for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your
>   axis2.xml file!

This may be frustrating because the HTTP transport receiver is properly defined in axis2.xml :

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer">
  <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
  <!-- [...] -->
</transportReceiver>
```

Why this warning occurs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says, if an **HTTPS** transport sender is defined, then you need to declare the corresponding transport receiver also to define, at least, the HTTPS port number.

cf. https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/servlet-transport.html#Configuring_axis2.xml

Then, the configuration should look like :

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

That's all !

Answer (score 0):

Undeploying and then redeploying Axis2 has solved this problem for me (I have Tomcat 8.5.20 on Windows 10, Axis2 v1.7.6):

1. From Tomcat Web Application Manager (in my case, http://localhost:8080/manager/html), click the **Undeploy** button next to Axis2.
2. Download a new WAR distribution of Axis2 from the official page https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html.
3. Unzip the archive and copy the **axis2.war** file to **%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps**.

Answer (score -1):

The warning is due to using the `SimpleHTTPServer` instead of the `AxisServletListener` as the warning said.